# C++ Stream Extraction Operator>> Declared But Not Defined Even Though It Is Defined

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I have in `stockType.h`

```
#include <iostream>
class stockType {
public:
    //...
    static friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const stockType& stock);
    static friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, stockType& stock);
private:
    //...
}
```

and in `stockType.cpp`

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const stockType& stock) {
    //...
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, stockType& stock) {
    //...
}
```

I'm having no issues with `operator<<` but the compiler gives me a fatal error "`static function 'std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &,stockType &)' declared but not defined`" and it says it occurs on main.cpp line 32 but there's only 31 lines in main.cpp.

Comment: You promised to make them static class functions, but you defined them as free functions. FYI friend is odd for class members. Remove `static`.

Comment: Hidden friends is a good way to do operator overloading. Otherwise it slows down the overload resolution stage. But yeah, no need for `static` here - it's already not a member function because it's a friend so `static` apparently refers to visibility here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking a free function (`friend` functions aren't methods in a class) as `static` indicates that it will be defined in the current translation unit. Putting a `static` function in a header means that all translation units including that header must have their own definition of that function. You should remove `static` from your declarations (clang and gcc actually reject your code as [invalid](https://godbolt.org/z/d66zvhhY3)).

Note that this is different to `static` member functions which indicate that the method is available in the class rather than in instances. This is one of the many confusing places that c++ uses the same keyword to mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: So since stream insertion and extraction operators aren't member functions, basically I can either declare them static outside the class or friend inside the class, but not both? I had an issue a previous time where I needed to make the overload static to fix it, but I think it was declared outside the class and not a friend.

Comment: @JustinIaconis stream operators (and operators in general) should not be static, they should be non-static members or free functions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719#4421719. If functions are defined in headers they should be marked `inline` not `static`